# Unresolved compilation problem: The method parseInt(String) is undefined for the type Integer

Tags: java, compiler-errors, undefined, parseint

Why it does not like parseInt? How to fix it?

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.*;

public class Table {

static class Data
{
    private String name = "";
    private int num = 0;

    public Data(String name, int num)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getNum()
    {
        return num;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " " + num;
    }
  }



   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
  {

    List<Data> table  = new ArrayList<Data>();

    try
    {
        String filename= ""C:\\input.txt";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while(line != null)
        {
            String[] tokens = line.split("[ ]+");

            String tempname = tokens[0];
            int tempnum = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);

            Data temp = new Data(tempname,tempnum);

            table.add(temp);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException n)
    {
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }
    catch(IOException a)
    {
        a.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(Data n:table)
    {
        System.out.println(n);
    }

       }

    }
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method parseInt(String) is undefined for the type Integer

at Table.main(Table.java:58)
```

Comment: Please remove the extra quotations in  file path:
String filename= ""C:\\input.txt";
Should be
String filename= "C:\\input.txt";

Comment: Thanks, but main problem is here - int tempnum = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);

Comment: Side note: splitting/parsing strings very often goes wrong. Always check for example, that your split gives you the expected number of elements; never just blindly access a certain index after split. And then: the exception says that you are trying to run a program that has compilation errors. Don't do that: the whole point of a compiled language is that you pay attention to the error messages from the compiler instead of blindly clicking the "run" button.

Comment: Do you have an own class called Integer?

Comment: Yes, I had a class Integer in the different file. Thanks! That was a problem!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in the code:

- Remove the imports

> import java.lang.*;

- The quotes around the path are not correct
- Your regular expression for the split() method is not correct, I guess. So assuming your input file has a format :

  ```
  name[]number
  ```

  the following should work:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  List<Data> table  = new ArrayList<Data>();

  try {
      String filename= "/home/kiflem/input.txt";
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
      String line = reader.readLine();

      while(line != null) {
          String[] tokens = line.split("\\[\\s*\\]+");
          if (tokens != null && tokens.length == 2) {
              String tempname = tokens[0];
              int tempnum = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
              Data temp = new Data(tempname,tempnum);
              table.add(temp);
           }
           line = reader.readLine();
       }
          .............
  ```
- If your delimiter is whitespace then use

> "\\s+"

as your regular expression.